# Is there any way to resize a Surface by any natural number value in ROBLOX?

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been working with the built-in Resize function in Roblox Studio and have been using it to expand the Top Surface of multiple Parts in order to form a wall-like structure.

The only problem that has arisen when using this method is that the surface of the wall created is not even: Some Parts are higher than others.

I later discovered that this problem is due to the fact that the built-in Resize function only takes integers as it's second parameter (or "expand-by" value). Ideally I need the Parts to have the ability expand by any Real Number.

Are there any alternatives to the built-in Resize function that allow one to resize a Surface by any Real Number?

Comment: Title should read "Is there any way to resize a Surface by any real number value in ROBLOX?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it actually requires a custom function to do so. With some fairly basic math we can write a simple function to accomplish such a task:

```
local Resize
do
    local directions = {
        [Enum.NormalId.Top] = {Scale=Vector3.new(0,1,0),Position=Vector3.new(0,1,0)},
        [Enum.NormalId.Bottom] = {Scale=Vector3.new(0,1,0),Position=Vector3.new(0,-1,0)},
        [Enum.NormalId.Right] = {Scale=Vector3.new(1,0,0),Position=Vector3.new(1,0,0)},
        [Enum.NormalId.Left] = {Scale=Vector3.new(1,0,0),Position=Vector3.new(-1,0,0)},
        [Enum.NormalId.Front] = {Scale=Vector3.new(0,0,1),Position=Vector3.new(0,0,1)},
        [Enum.NormalId.Back] = {Scale=Vector3.new(0,0,1),Position=Vector3.new(0,0,-1)},
    }

    function Resize(p, d, n, c)
        local prop = c and 'Position' or 'CFrame'
        p.Size = p.Size + directions[d].Scale*n
        p[prop] = p[prop] + directions[d].Position*(n/2)
        return p.Size, p[prop]
    end
end


Resize(workspace.Part, Enum.NormalId.Bottom, 10, false) --Resize workspace.Part downards by 10 studs, ignoring collisions
```

If you're interested more on how and why this code works the way it does, here's a link to a pastebin that's loaded with comments, which I felt would be rather ugly for the answer here: http://pastebin.com/LYKDWZnt